# How to implement Side Sheet Dialog in Android

Tags: android

I have seen it used in apps like Discord mobile apps where you swipe the sides to open the window that shows the list of active members.

Is there any way to create modal dialog that shows from right side? The screenshot below is from Google's own Material Design website but I can't find any support libraries that allows me to create side sheet dialog. The closest one is `BottomSheetDialog` but it slides from bottom only.

[image]

Comment: `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: It is ok to have two ```DrawerLayout``` in one activity?

Comment: Technically, yes, but if you mean that you want two drawers – one on either side – you can do that with a single `DrawerLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

you can look on their github to see how to implement the side sheet: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/SideSheet.md

For modal side sheet :

```
val sideSheetDialog = SideSheetDialog(requireContext())
sideSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name_for_side_sheet)

sideSheetDialog.show()
sideSheetDialog.hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NavigationView with `android:layout_gravity="end"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    />
```